# view xml content result from web service response in php

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, schema

I'm creating php page that connect to a web service and will display the result from the web service,
the xml for the web service response is like this:

```
<GetUserResponse xmlns="http://the web service">
  <GetUserResult>
    <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml
  </GetUserResult>
</GetUserResponse>
```

I need to know the xml content that I got from the service,
and how to deal with it or display it in my page?

---

#### Solved

I was able to solve it using:

$xml =simplexml_load_string($result);

Answer (score 0):

```
XML File : myxml.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
    <to>Gauttam</to>
    <from>Kevadia</from>
    <heading>My Heading</heading>
    <body>Body Content Here!!!!</body>
</note> 

TO read in PHP return with Object :

<?php
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("myxml.xml");
    echo $xml->to . "<br>";
    echo $xml->from . "<br>";
    echo $xml->heading . "<br>";
    echo $xml->body;
    // IF XML file having multiple value retrieve it dynamic with array 
?>
```